# QGIS cannot load macro function?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

This has me stumped. For some reason, I can no longer run a function from a project macro even though macros are enabled (from `Settings > Options > General > Enable macros > Always`).

Just a simple test like the following fails:

[image: Macro test]

Same applies if I make `test_print()` a function on its own. I.e.:

```
def openProject():
    pass

def test_print():
    print 'It works'

...
```

Any ideas? I'm using QGIS 2.14.1-Essen for Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-tested this on **QGIS 2.14 LTR** and it works fine so it was perhaps a minor bug.